# I am using Ajax to link two select tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax to link two select tags where one is state and other is cities of the selected state. Everything is working fine. The problem is that when I select a state I get cities of that particular state but when I change the state again, I don't get the cities for the new state for that I have to refresh the page. Kindly help. !! 
Thanks !

```
//**HTML**

        <select class="select_state" onchange="getCity();">
         <option value="">Select State</option>
           <?php $stateSql = "SELECT * FROM state" ;
                 $stateResult = $conn->query($stateSql);
                 while($sRow = $stateResult->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "<option value='".$sRow['name']."'".">".$sRow['name'];"  </option>";
                 }?></select>
        function getCity(val) {
          var val = $('.select_state').val();
          //alert(val);
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get_city.php",
          data:'city_name='+val,
          success: function(data){
            $("#cities").append(data);
          }
          });
```

get_city.php:

```
    <?php
    include 'dbConfig.php';

     $a=$_POST['city_name'];
     if(!empty($_POST["city_name"])) {
        $citySql ="SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city_state LIKE '$a'";
        $cityResult = $conn->query($citySql);
                        while($cRow = $cityResult->fetch_assoc()) 
                        {
                          //echo $cRow['city_name'];
                          echo "<option value='".$cRow['city_name'].">".$cRow['city_name'];"</option>";
                        }
     }
    ?>
```

[image: Attached copy of the code]

Comment: Please post code at text, not as an image. Or better [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Does your `getCity()` function gets "cities"? Really? Or am I missing something?

Comment: instead of append(data) try with html(data) or text(data)

Comment: Like @whoami is starting to say, the issue isn't that it doesn't get the new values, the issue is that you just keep appending new values and never clearing out the old ones. If you scrolled down you would likely see the new values added. What you need to do in your ajax success callback is replace the values in the select with something like `$('#cities').html(data)` or clear all the values in the box with something like `$('#cities').empty()` first.

Comment: Thanks guys !! @whoami ... html(data) worked.. Jonathan .... ill now try clearing.. KIKO Software : Ya it can now..!! hehe

Comment: @KalpeshShende, is it working fine after html(data)?

Comment: @KalpeshShende, if you my solution worked, why don't the accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of append(data) try with html(data).

```
$("#cities").html(data);
```